# Excel function not evaluating last IF Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, false-positive

I have this function that compares cells and the data that is stored within the cell.

**Function:**

```
=IF($D2=$A$54,IF($H2>(2*$D$54),"Great","Low"),IF($D2=$A$55,IF($H2>(2*$D$55),"Great","Low"),IF($D2=$A$56,IF($H2>(2*$D$56),"Great","Low"),IF($D2=$A$57,**IF($H2>(2*$D$57),"Great","Low"),IF($D2=$A$58,IF($H2>(2*$D$58),"Great","Low")**)))))
```

**This part of the function:**

```
IF($H2>(2*$D$57),"Great","Low"),IF($D2=$A$58,IF($H2>(2*$D$58),"Great","Low")** is evaluating as False instead of the value Great or Low.
```

I don't understand whether or not I should use an AND or OR to make the function evaluate. Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: You don't have an "else" on your next-to-last IF. (IF($D2=$A$58 .... ) What should happen if D2 is none of A54, A55, A56, A57, A58?

Comment: I understand what you saying, but the D2 has to be one of the A#. so what could I put for a filler? These " " (quotations)? I tried IF($D2=$A$58,IF($H2>(2*$D$58),"Great","Low", 0) and then it evaluates to 0 so I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Missing Else part on Line 21 below:

`=IF($D2=$A$54
    ,IF($H2>(2*$D$54)
        ,"Great"
        ,"Low")
    ,IF($D2=$A$55
        ,IF($H2>(2*$D$55)
            ,"Great"
            ,"Low")
        ,IF($D2=$A$56
            ,IF($H2>(2*$D$56)
                ,"Great"
                ,"Low")
            ,IF($D2=$A$57
                ,IF($H2>(2*$D$57)
                    ,"Great"
                    ,"Low")
                ,IF($D2=$A$58
                    ,IF($H2>(2*$D$58)
                        ,"Great"
                        ,"Low"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)`

Comment: I understand what you saying, but the D2 has to be one of the A#. so what could I put for a filler? These " " (quotations)? I tried IF($D2=$A$58,IF($H2>(2*$D$58),"Great","Low", 0) and then it evaluates to 0 so I'm confused